# Detect if polygon has intersecting lines (bowtie)

Tags: ios, algorithm, google-maps, math, polygon

I'm looking for a way to detect if a set of points/coordinates have any intersecting lines.

A little setup, I'm drawing a polygon using UIBezierPath on an overlay to a map. This all works. I'm able to reduce the map points down using a point reducing algorithm, and I'm left with a simple looking polygon that renders on my map just fine. FWIW, I'm using Google Maps SDK.

My problem is that it is possible for the user to draw a polygon with self intersecting lines (which is a problem for what I am doing). I need to be able to do one of 3 things.

- Remove the intersecting points in the array. (Clip off the bow tie pieces)
- Detect if my points have this bow tie (I'll just tell them to redraw a new polygon)
- If possible (which I don't think it is), prevent the path from drawing the bow tie in the first place.

I mostly see the bow tie when the polygon self closes and the end point is slightly underlapping the start point. So when the polygon closes and renders into map coordinates on the map, I get a tiny bow tie that messes with an internal API.

Is there anything out there that will work using map coordinates? I've seen some fixes for regular CGPoints, but nothing that will take map coordinates. I would prefer to do this check on my polygon after it has gone through my reducer as it leaves many less points to check. Performance is an issue, and would prefer not to iterate over hundreds of points directly coming off the UIBezierPath. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the Google Maps SDK or the UIBezierPath. I assume that you are given a polygon in the 2D plane  and you would like to automatically detect where the polygon intersects itself (if it does).

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is checking *all* pairs of edges whether they intersect or not. You can check this in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time where n is the number of edges, as there are n*(n-1)/2 pairs of edges. For a given pair of edges, here are the details how to do it:

- [How to check if two given line segments intersect?](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/)

Nothing extraordinary but the details do require attention.

A more sophisticated algorithm is the plane sweep algorithm:

- [Line segment intersection](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sitharam/COURSES/CG/kreveldintrolinesegment.pdf), starting at slide 25
- [Line Segment Intersection Using a Sweep Line Algorithm](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/163/notes05/seg_intersection_handout.pdf)